# How to make a gif or short mp4 video in python from figures containing multiple different animations on it?

Tags: python

I want to create a gif or mp4 of multiple figures in python, thus containing at least four animations. I have four different groups of figures, and if I create four different gifs from those, How can I place them in one frame? [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HMVA3fa6ra0iKR6IifquQzebN9nvIURJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What have you tried so far that hasn't worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the images as a bunch of pngs, then you can create a gif like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imageio

# Create PNGs
y = np.random.randint(30, 40, size=(40))
for i in range(4):
    plt.plot(y[:i - 3])
    plt.ylim(20,50)
    plt.savefig('1.png')
    plt.close()
    
# Build GIF
png_list = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png'] # Order of images
with imageio.get_writer('mygif.gif', mode='I') as writer:
    for filename in png_list:
        image = imageio.imread(filename)
        writer.append_data(image)
```

The source has some examples with smoother transitions if you're interested.

Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/basics-of-gifs-with-pythons-matplotlib-54dd544b6f30